# Can a professor in the program I'm applying to write a recommendation letter?

Tags: phd, application, recommendation-letter

Three professors have promised to write me recommendation letters for PhD program applications. I want to apply to the program where one of them (Prof.A) is a professor. I was in his summer research program and I'm still a member of his group. He knows me pretty well and speaks highly of me. I talked to him about the application and he told me I could apply directly.

Do I need to find another professor to write me a recommendation letter for Prof.A's program? It seems weird to use his recommendation letter to apply for his program. But he knows me quite well and I don't think the SOP or recommendation will give him any surprise information about me. The three professors are very familiar with me and I don't think other professors can write letters stronger than them.

Comment: Who will be reviewing the application prof A himself or other people at his institute?

Comment: @TimRias I think other people will be responsible for reviewing applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fine. Certainly in the US. The professor will probably need to not participate otherwise in the admissions decision directly, but that is a separate issue for them, not for yourself. If there is an issue then he would tell you, I'd assume.

It is probably better, actually, to do it this way than to have him work behind the scenes in some way.